# How to check individual component in the Visual basic. Error checking

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, components

In the text box, I only want a 3 number combination of 0 and 1 as 011,110,111,001, etc. How can I write to check individual component(from three numbers) is 0 or 1, and specify this for checking error?
I want to have a if statement if possible.
For example,
If the number is 015, this message will be shown.

MsgBox("Please Insert a combination of 0,1 into the text box.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply restrict character entry to zeroes and ones as the user enters them, and limit the length.  You'll have to adjust this code for the proper `If` checks; I'm a C# guy, not a VB guy.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar <> ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
        If Textbox1.Length < 3 and (e.KeyChar = "0" or e.KeyChar = "1") Then
        Else
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is a property of `System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I see. I don't want to have another sub going on for my error checking code, is there other ways to just check individual component of the combination to see if its zero or one?